# Gatsby: Environment variables .env return undefined

Tags: docker, nginx, gatsby, traefik

I am working on a static website using **Gatsby** for the development and **Nginx** for serving the static files.

I am also using **Docker** for the deployment to test and production and **Traefik** for routing traffic to the docker container of the application.

I have an environment variable which I defined in the application file, and that environment variable is called from a `.env` file in the root folder of the application.

However, when that environment variable is invoked in the application, it throws an error:

> undefined

**Here's the code**:

**Dockerfile**

```
# Set base image
FROM node:latest AS builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and install packages
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

# Copy other project files and build
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# Set nginx image
FROM nginx:latest

# Nginx config
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Static build
COPY --from=builder /app/public /usr/share/nginx/html

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

**.env**

```
GATSBY_API_URL=https://myapi.mywebsite.com
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: my-website
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      GATSBY_API_URL: ${GATSBY_API_URL}
    expose:
      - "80"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.my-website.rule=Host(`my-website.com`)
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: traefik-proxy
```

**index.js**

```
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.GATSBY_API_URL}/api/EmployeeDetail/verify`, values)
            // console.log(res, 'verify endpoint');
            if( res.data.requestSuccessful === true ) {
                dispatchVerifyData({ 
                    type : 'UPDATE_VERIFY_DATA', 
                    verifyData: {
                        res: res.data.responseData,
                        loanType: values.loanType
                    }
                })
                handleNext()
            } else {
                setIsSuccessful({
                    status: false,
                    message: res.data.message
                })
            }            

        } catch (error) {
            //error state Unsuccessful 
            console.log(error, 'error')
            setIsSuccessful({
                status: false,
            })
        }

    }
```

**.dockerignore**

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
.DS_Store
.bin
.git
.gitignore
.bundleignore
.bundle
.byebug_history
.rspec
tmp
log
test
config/deploy
public/packs
public/packs-test
yarn-error.log
coverage/
.env
.env.production
```

**Nginx default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires -1;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

I can't still seem to tell what is the cause of the issue that causes the application to return an **undefined error** whenever the environment variable is invoked. Any form of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it after some long hours of debugging with my colleagues.

**Here are a few things I learnt**:

**Firstly, by default, Gatsby supports 2 environments**:

1. **Development**. If you run `gatsby develop`, then you will be in the `development` environment.
2. **Production**. If you run `gatsby build` or `gatsby serve`, then you will be in the `production` environment.

If you note, however, we are running `npm run build` in our `Dockerfile` which is equivalent to `gatsby build`, so this informs the application that we are running in the `production`. environment.

**Secondly, defining Environment Variables for Client-side JavaScript**

For Project Env Vars that you want to access in client-side browser JavaScript, you can define an environment config file, `.env.development` and/or `.env.production`, in your root folder. Depending on your active environment, the correct one will be found and its values embedded as environment variables in the browser JavaScript.

In otherwords, we will need to rename our environment config file from `.env` to `.env.production` to allow the Gatsby application to recognize it in our `production` environment.

**Thirdly,  defining Environment Variables using prefixes**

In addition to these Project Environment Variables defined in `.env.*` files, you could also define OS Env Vars. OS Env Vars which are prefixed with `GATSBY_` will become available in browser JavaScript.

If you note very well we are already defining this in our `.env` config file as - `GATSBY_API_URL=https://myapi.mywebsite.com`, so we have no issues with that.

**Fourthly, removing the env. config files from .dockerignore**

If we observe clearly how the values of environment variables are embedded in the browser Javascript for Client-side JavaScript, you will see that it is done during build time and not run time.

Therefore, we need to remove the `.env.*` config files from `.dockerignore` and also remove the `environment` option in the `docker-compose.yml` file, since it is unnecessary anymore because we don't embed the values of the environment variables during the run time.

**So our code will look like this now**:

**Dockerfile**

```
# Set base image
FROM node:latest AS builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and install packages
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

# Copy other project files and build
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# Set nginx image
FROM nginx:latest

# Nginx config
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Static build
COPY --from=builder /app/public /usr/share/nginx/html

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

**.env.production**

```
GATSBY_API_URL=https://myapi.mywebsite.com
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: my-website
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "80"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.my-website.rule=Host(`my-website.com`)
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: traefik-proxy
```

**index.js**

```
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.GATSBY_API_URL}/api/EmployeeDetail/verify`, values)
            // console.log(res, 'verify endpoint');
            if( res.data.requestSuccessful === true ) {
                dispatchVerifyData({ 
                    type : 'UPDATE_VERIFY_DATA', 
                    verifyData: {
                        res: res.data.responseData,
                        loanType: values.loanType
                    }
                })
                handleNext()
            } else {
                setIsSuccessful({
                    status: false,
                    message: res.data.message
                })
            }            

        } catch (error) {
            //error state Unsuccessful 
            console.log(error, 'error')
            setIsSuccessful({
                status: false,
            })
        }

    }
```

**.dockerignore**

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
.DS_Store
.bin
.git
.gitignore
.bundleignore
.bundle
.byebug_history
.rspec
tmp
log
test
config/deploy
public/packs
public/packs-test
yarn-error.log
coverage/
```

**Nginx default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires -1;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**